# Group by in Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

In my rails application I have following models

```
Transaction
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :agent
  belongs_to :program
```

And here is the query i used to get data

```
def self.efficiency_report(starts=nil, ends=nil)
sql = "SELECT p.abbreviation,ag.name,
         t.miles, t.date
        FROM transactions t
        inner join accounts a on t.account_id = a.id
        inner join programs p on a.program_id = p.id
        inner join agents ag on t.agent_id = ag.id
        Group by p.id , ag.id" 
 result_array(sql)
end


def self.result_array(sql)
  conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  res = conn.execute(sql)
  results = []
  res.each{|r|
    results << r
  }
  return results
end
```

I want to render data in view with group by program first then group by agent name under it then miles, like this

```
Program:AA
  Agent:Bob
    Miles          Date 
    1234           02/12/2012           
    5463           03/12/2012 
 Agent:Ben
    Miles          Date 
    234           02/22/2012           
    344           01/02/2012 

Program:BB
  Agent:Bob
    Miles          Date 
    1234           02/12/2012           
    5463           03/12/2012 
  Agent:Ben
    Miles          Date 
    234           02/22/2012           
    344           01/02/2012
```

For this i m doing following in my view

```
%h2 Vendor Efficiency Report
- @transactions.group_by(&:row[0]).sort.each { |data, transaction|
%h2= data.row[0]
- transaction.group_by(&:row[1]).sort.each { |data, transaction|
%table#data_table.display{:cellpadding => "0", :cellspacing => "0"}
  %h3{:style => "clear:both;margin-left:10px"}= data.row[1]
  %thead
    %tr.odd
      %td.bold{:style => "width:60px;"} Miles
      %td.bold{:style => "width:60px;"} Date
  - for t in transaction
    %tbody
      %tr
       %td{:style => "width:60px;"}= row[2] 
       %td{:style => "width:60px;"}= row[3]
  -}
-}
= will_paginate @transactions
```

But i m getting this error

**wrong argument type String (expected Proc)**

Will anyone let me know what i m doing wrong here or is there any other better way for grouping?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `group_by` calls. I'm not sure what `&:row[0]` is doing, but it's passing a string as argument. I think this is what you're looking for:

```rb
@transactions.group_by{ |r| r[0] }...
```

**Edit**

Just figured out what `&:row[0]` was doing. It's a call to the `Symbol#[]` method, which returns the character at the index given (essentially, as if it were a`String`). The call `:row[0]` returns the first character of the string `"row"`.

So basically, it was as if you were calling:

```
@transactions.group_by(&"r")
```

Comment: Interesting, I just did some tests: `:row[0]` gives you the first character of the String `"row"` (i.e. `"r"`). Weird. I had never seen that syntax before.

Comment: when we get complete modal in result from action then we can use &: like this "@transactions.group_by(&:payment_date).sort.each { |date, transaction|" where payment_date is once column in transaction

Comment: Oh, it doesn't have to be a model for that to work. The argument you pass just has to be a `Symbol` that represents a method on the objects in the array. (Actually, if you want the detailed answer, the argument can be anything for which the method `to_proc` is defined, which is true for symbols, not for strings). Try this: `%w[abcd a abc abcdefg abcde].sort_by(&:length)`